# Resx Error While Converting From VS2003

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

I'm converting a legacy application originally developed using Visual Studio 2003. Now I got stuck with the following error which appears while building the solution:

```
Invalid Resx file. Region name 'cb' is not supported.
```

It doesn't makes much sense to me. I'd appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

==============

Another bit of information on the problem. Attached image shows the error message I see when open the form.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/988d31bbfa.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/988d31bbfa.jpg)

I wonder how can I disable using of this 'cb' region.

To see enlarged image - [Link](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/988d31bbfa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I ended up with creating new resx files using Visual Studio 2008. I created them, filled with the original content and replaced old files with the newly created.

At least the solution can be built after this. Hopefully there will be no problems in runtime.